# android: display an image in the middle of the screen programatically

Tags: java, android, imageview

I've an image (image1.png)

When I click on some button, I want this image to be displayed in the middle of the screen for a second and disappear. How can I do it?

I guess that it brings me the center coordinates of the screen.

```
public void onClick(View button) {
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( dm );
    int screenMiddlePointWidth = dm.widthPixels / 2;
    int screenMiddlePointHeight = dm.heightPixels / 2;
}
```

p.s. I don't want the image to push other views on the screen so I can't set it as invisible\gone

Comment: create an activity and place the layout in the center. Dynamically set the image in the imageview. Create a handler which finishes the new activity after a certain interval

Comment: but can't it be something like this( the word "sweet")? https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZudiRol-4sk/maxresdefault.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi use this code in xml to place your image in center

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and then in java file use the following code

```
ImageView img;
img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview);
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
img.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
};
timer.start();
```

you can use the timer code in onCreate method or anywhere you want.

If you want to center your image programatically use the following code.

```
image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) image.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
img.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: thanks but it will affect the other displayed views' location on the screen, won't it? because when it's visible\gone, they will move as I guess..

Comment: image.setImageDrawable(null); 
this will only clear the image in imageview instead of making imageview invisible, you can also replace transparent image with original to hide original one.

Comment: if your imageview is in center of screen? where are other views? and what are other views?

Comment: imagine that I've a screen with text lines. when I press on a button at the bottom of the screen, I want some image to be shown for a second on top of all the lines, in the middle of the screen..

Comment: I used AlertDialog with the image, combining your CountDownTimer. thanks :)